# Manual (automatic) Segue not working - table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'm new to Xcode and I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) which goes through how to add a manual segue.

https://github.com/AdditionAddict/learnXcode

**Problem**: When clicking on a table cell in the simulator the manual segue is not triggered.

**What I've tried**: I've added a manual (automatic) segue, an identifier, and whilst the tutorial says as this point a selection of a cell with result in going from the table view cell to the meal detail scene, I've continued to the code part and my breakpoint in `prepare` still does not trigger.

```
    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        
        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {
            
        case "AddItem":
            os_log("Adding a new meal", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            
        case "ShowDetail":
            // set the meal for the `MealViewController` as the meal selected in the `MealTableViewController`
            os_log("Show detail of a meal", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            
            guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? MealViewController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination, \(segue.destination)")
            }
            guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender, \(String(describing: sender))")
            }
            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }
            
            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
            
        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier")
        }
    }
```

**Checks made**:
If, for the purposes of debugging only, I put the following in my `MealTableViewController.swift` with a breakpoint nothing happens when I click a table cell:

```
    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

This makes me think the table cells aren't registering a 'selection'.

Table View Selection property is Single Selection.

The custom `MealTableViewCell` has `User Interaction Enabled` checked.

Clicking the `MealTableViewCell` in the outline pane and selecting the Connections inspector in the utilities pane also shows the segue:

[image: Connections Inspector showing segue]

**Final bits**: Is it still possible to add a manual (automatic) segue?
Tutorial is in archive and I've managed to follow most of it with small changes.
Using Xcode 11.6

[image: main.storyboard and Identity Inspector]

**Edit(s) / answers to comment questions**:

1. added (automatic) to manual. I mean the method the tutorial uses from table cell to meal detail.
2. There isn't anything in front of the table (that I'm aware of) such as a tap gesture recogniser
3. The Plus segue works and triggers the `prepare` unlike clicking a table cell

Comment: "This makes me think the table cells aren't registering a 'selection'." -> have you tried debugging that? Might there be something in front of the table or the cell that might be receiving the touch event, for example?

Comment: checkout Don Vaughn's answer 
 here - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619139/prepareforsegue-is-not-getting-called-when-i-click-on-a-button-without-using-per)

Comment: @matt I've added the repo. I double-checked the User Interaction Enabled based on other SO questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have accidentally disabled user interaction for the *table view*. (I knew this was the problem the moment I ran the project and discovered that I couldn't scroll the table view or click any of the stars to change the rating.)

Look at the bottom of this screen shot. You need to make sure that User Interaction Enabled is *checked* as in the screen shot. In your project, it is not. Hence the whole table is "untouchable."

[image]

Comment: Note that you will have some other problems once you get the table view working; you need to delete your implementation of `didSelect`, as it now conflicts with the automatic segue and will cause issues.

Comment: no problem, that was for debugging this issue. I'll award the bounty once I can.

Comment: no worries, the main thing is you're up and running again